# Foreign Keys and Compοund PKs

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I largely like to work on my more complex tables using mySQL Workbench's EER diagrams.  I use it to define foreign keys between tables.  I understand that a foreign key should be indexed, but when I use Workbench to draw the relationship to another table, it creates a compound PK effectively creating an index.

So I'm a little hazy on this.  Must foreign keys be part of a compound PK for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are either setting up your foreign keys incorrectly or misreading what you are seeing.
PKs appear in the image of a Key in the EER diagram while FKs will appear as either a filled in red diamond or a empty red diamond, depending if it is defaulted to Null or not.

By definition a PK is indexed for doing fast lookups, etc...By definition, mysql will also set up a constraint and index for a [FK relationship](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Have a look at the EER diagram for the sakila dabatabase that you can download with mysql workbench. This is a good example to follow if you are having trouble setting up a proper FK relationship using the EER tool in mysql workbench. [image]